# Exception thrown when closing Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, exception

I have built an application that starts a Form using `Application.Run(new Form)`. Within the application there is this following thread function

```
private void threadTask() {
  while (true) {
    Thread.Sleep(500);
      if (isOn) {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { reloadData(tabControl.SelectedIndex); });
        Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { onOffButton.BackColor = Color.Lime; });
        Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { infoLabel.Visible = false; });
    }
  }
}
```

When I close the application I get this exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)

I have have tried to solve this by calling `Application.Exit()` when the Form gets closed. The function gets executed, however, I still get the exception after the `Application.Exit()` got called.

Is there some way I can work around this? How do I check that the Application is getting closed?

Comment: Debug in vs and check wich line throughs exception. I guess you need terminate threads befor exiting application

Comment: It's pretty random. I happens with any of the three Invoke lines, sometimes not at all.

Comment: so like i said you have to terminate them befor exit the application

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, no good, specific answer could be given. But, your question really is just a variation on other duplicates, wherein you have code that should not be executing after you start exiting the application. It's up to you to write code to coordinate between code that wants access to the UI objects (like, calling `Invoke()`) and code that will make this impossible (like, exiting the application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your Forms gets closed while the thread is still running, there is the possibility that one of the invokes is called after the form is closed and before the thread is aborted.
That invoke tries to execute the delegate in the context of the UI-thread of the form (which is no longer running).

Solution: you need to  use a mechanism that can stop the thread from running (in the OnClosing event of the form).

I would suggest using a `Task` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming) which you can cancel using a `CancellationToken`.

Note: in the `Task`, you need to check the `CancellationToken` before calling the `Invoke` methods to make sure they are only called if there is no cancellation requested.

Comment: You can cancel nothing with a CancellationToken. It will just store a request for cancellation. You can ask the token if such a request was made. This is not limited to a task, you can do it whereever and in whatever context

Comment: @Sir Rufo: your remark was certainly implied in my answer, and explained in the included link...